# Get error messages when I have a syntax error?

Tags: php

I have a class and the commented line is failing (clearly because I don't need the `$` before `displayname`), however I ended up having to put a bunch of `echo` statements in to figure that out because an error isn't being thrown.

I'm hoping there is a way.

```
class RegisterModel {
    var $displayname;
    ...
    function RegisterModel() {
        try {
            if (empty($_POST) === false) {
                // THIS LINE IS FAILING ... BUT I'M NOT GETTING AN ERROR
                // I KNOW WHY IT'S FAILING ... BUT I WANT AN ERROR TO THROW
                $this->$displayname = $_POST['displayname'];
                ...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Should the error be getting thrown into the `catch` and I'm just not using it right? Is there some global setting I need to set so that the errors are thrown?

Comment: This is when you catch PHP clicking its heels together and saying "I wish I was a real language" over and over.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I have to say that I love that comment! +1 my friend!

Comment: Well, define a `error_hendler` to throw exceptions on errors? *by default they aren't exceptions). See `set_error_handler` and go. PHP has many shortcomings, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Wrikken, so I can build a shared `function` and have that called on error. Presumably I can then *log* the error and then redirect to an error page -- is that correct? **Also**, on another note, I am coming from 12 years of .NET programming and I'm trying to get used to PHP. There are things I really like. But I have to admit that sometimes I *feel* like that during this process.

Comment: You can do with you want in the function, throw exceptions, log errors, `die()` a horrible death, redirecting _only_ when there's not been output sent to client yet (or still in output buffer). And keep in mind `.NET` is more a framework, PHP is a language, in which you could use one of the many frameworks, build your own, or go without. So, 'vanilla' PHP doesn't really compare in functionality.

Comment: I guess my definition of failing and yours differ.  It sounds like you are trying to throw an exception if $_POST['displayname'] is not set.  You should use isset($_POST['displayname']) to do that.

Comment: @gview: (1) it fails on $this->$displayname (2) as the OP states, he doesn't care about the / this specific error, but the general error handling.

Comment: @Wrikken: That assignment at best generates a notice.  You should have made it clear that the only way your advice works is if the error level is set to include notices.  Clearly his is not, which is why the assignment is made without issue.

Comment: @gview: No, the error handler wiil _always_ be called, even for `@`- prefixed calls (which makes it `0`), or any level. The code in the error handler itself is responsible for checking the errno with the current `error_reporting` level (though one should), _and_ I stated as much in the answer below. His issue is that regardless of error reporting (not triggering, that will always happen) level, it does not use exceptions but 'normal' errors, and so is not suited for a `try{} catch{}` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set_error_handler(function($errno ,$errstr,$errfile,$errline,$errcontext){
   if($errno & error_reporting()) throw new Exception($errstr,$errno);
});
```

Keep in mind you want to set `error_reporting` to your desired level.

Comment: Oh, I see, so when the `Exception` is thrown here it would hit the `try...catch` that I have setup?

Comment: Yep, but keep in mind some errors are non-recoverable, so the script will still die there & then. Syntax errors and the like (can't run 'custom' error handlers if the syntax is iffy).

Comment: When you stated `Syntax errors and the like (can't run 'custom' error handlers if the syntax is iffy).` does that mean the error I'm trying to catch (*the fact that it's syntactically wrong*) isn't going to end up in this callback?

Comment: @Michael: As wacky as it may seem... that isn't a syntax error.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, hmm, that's interesting.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud:  It's not a syntax error to reference a class variable using a variable.  So while I understand that in this context, it was a coding mistake you made, and you would like PHP to catch that for you, that seems to me to be the purpose of a Lint or Notice feature.  There are many uses for runtime resolution of a variable in order to manipulate an object variable or method. I think your argument might be that at runtime, if $displayname has not been asssigned that your code is essentially trying to assign something to $this->NULL at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, `$foo = 'bar'; $this->$foo === $this->bar;`, so having `$foo=NULL` (or not existant) is a runtime error, not a syntax one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If this displays the error, you have a potential run-time configuration error. You could adjust your configuration accordingly if it's impossible. You can look at the various error-related variables defined [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting).